# Cant get to index correctly

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I know my code is messy bear with me. I just want to get it working and then I will make it clean. Yes I know some parts aren't finished but It keeps saying index is out of range and I cant figure out where to put + 1's and stuff like that to make it all line up. I know its an easy fix i'm just not sure what I have to change to make it index correctly.

```
def main():
    questions_answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', "A", 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', ]
    questions_input = [''] * 20
    questions_wrong = ['']
    amount_correct = 0
    amount_incorrect = 0

    question_number = 1
    while question_number <= 10:
        questions_input = input('Enter Your answer for Question #' + str(question_number + 1) +': ')
        questions_input = questions_input.upper
        question_number += 1

    if questions_input == questions_answers[question_number]:
        amount_correct + 1
    else:
        questions_wrong.append(questions_input + 1)
        amount_incorrect

    print()
        
    if amount_correct >= 15:
        print('**YOU PASSED**')
    else:
        print('**YOU FAILED**')

    print('Number correct: ', format(amount_correct, '.2f'))

    print('Number incorrect:', format(amount_incorrect, '.2f'))
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print('You got the following questions wrong:')
    print()
    print('Question     Correct     Your Answer')
    print('--------     -------     -----------')
    print(questions_wrong)    
    print(questions_input)

main()
```

Comment: Why do you initialize `questions_input` to a list, then overwrite it with the user's input?

Comment: im going to be honest, im new to arrays i really dont know hahaha

Comment: `questions_input = questions_input.upper` sets that variable to a function object, not the result.  You are not CALLING that function.  Add `()` at the end.

Comment: `questions_input + 1` can't work. `questions_input` is a string, you can't add a number to it.

Comment: You start with `question_number = 1` and then print `question_number + 1`.  Did you really mean to use `for question_number in range(10):` here?  `question_number` will be 11 when you exit the loop.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The statements `amount_correct + 1` and `amount_incorrect` do nothing at all.

Comment: Why are you asking for 10 answers before checking if the answer is correct? Maybe that `if` statement should be inside the loop?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have no idea why it pasted as 10 its supposed to be 20

Comment: Very simply, there are many things wrong with this script. You need to start over, thinking more carefully about what you're doing. You won't learn anything if someone here corrects it for you.

Comment: @Barmar I have a list of correct answers. Im asking the user to input what they think the correct answer is, storing that answer, and then checking to see if they were right or wrong.

Comment: But you're doing the check after the `while` loop is done. So you're only checking the last answer they gave. And you get an index error because when the loop is done, `question_number` is outside the length of the list.

Comment: @Barmar I said it wasn't done... I'm very far from done I said that. I've encountered a bug and cannot fix it that is why I am here. Once I fix this I can move onto the smaller problems.

Comment: Assuming you really had "20" in your original code, your bug is that your loop is running from 2 to 21 (because you start from 1 and immediately bump the number), and Python numbers the list from 0 to 19.  When you refer to `questions_answers[20]`, it goes boom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start with minimal changes, although your arrays are of size 20 and you loop only 10

```py
def main():
    questions_answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', "A", 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', ]
    questions_input = [''] * 20
    questions_wrong = [''] * 20
    amount_correct = 0
    amount_incorrect = 0

    question_number = 0
    while question_number < 10:
        questions_input[question_number] = input('Enter Your answer for Question #' + str(question_number + 1) +': ')
        
        if questions_input[question_number] == questions_answers[question_number]:
            amount_correct += 1
        else:
            questions_wrong[question_number] = questions_input[question_number]
            amount_incorrect += 1

        question_number += 1

    print()
        
    if amount_correct >= 15:
        print('**YOU PASSED**')
    else:
        print('**YOU FAILED**')

    print('Number correct: ', format(amount_correct, '.2f'))

    print('Number incorrect:', format(amount_incorrect, '.2f'))
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print('You got the following questions wrong:')
    print()
    print('Question     Correct     Your Answer')
    print('--------     -------     -----------')
    print(questions_wrong)    
    print(questions_input)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the correct and incorrect answers in separate lists makes it impossible to produce the report that you want to produce at the end, since you lose any record of which number each answer was -- all three lists will have different indices corresponding to the same question, so trying to use an index from one list in another list will get you either the wrong entry or an `IndexError` almost every time.

You *could* fix this by using two dictionaries instead of two lists (so you can make the keys in the dictionaries match the indices in the main answer list), but I suggest just storing a single list of the user's answers, which makes it easy to zip the correct answers with the user's answers:

```
correct_answers = list('BDAACABACDBCDADCCBDA')
user_answers = [
    input(f'Enter Your answer for Question #{n}: ').upper()
    for n in range(1, len(correct_answers) + 1)
]

num_correct = sum(c == u for c, u in zip(correct_answers, user_answers))
num_incorrect = len(user_answers) - num_correct
if num_correct >= 15:
    print('**YOU PASSED**')
else:
    print('**YOU FAILED**')

print(f'Number correct: {num_correct}')
print(f'Number incorrect: {num_incorrect}')
print()
print('You got the following questions wrong:')
print()
print('Question     Correct     Your Answer')
print('--------     -------     -----------')
for n, (c, u) in enumerate(zip(correct_answers, user_answers), 1):
    print(f'{n:<13}{c:<12}{u:<11}')
```

Comment: Thanks, but a lot of what you suggested are things I cant do. I have guidelines I have to follow.

Answer (score -1):

The following minor changes let your code run to completion.  The report at the end does not actually print what you say it will print, but I'll let you finish that part.

```
def main():
    questions_answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', "A", 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', ]
    questions_wrong = []
    amount_correct = 0
    amount_incorrect = 0

    for question_number in range(10):
        questions_input = input('Enter Your answer for Question #' + str(question_number + 1) +': ')
        questions_input = questions_input.upper()

        if questions_input == questions_answers[question_number]:
            amount_correct += 1
        else:
            questions_wrong.append((question_number+1,questions_input))
            amount_incorrect += 1

    print()
        
    if amount_correct >= 15:
        print('**YOU PASSED**')
    else:
        print('**YOU FAILED**')

    print('Number correct: ', format(amount_correct, '.2f'))

    print('Number incorrect:', format(amount_incorrect, '.2f'))
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print('You got the following questions wrong:')
    print()
    print('Question     Correct     Your Answer')
    print('--------     -------     -----------')
    print(questions_wrong)    
    print(questions_input)

main()
```

Output:

```
Enter Your answer for Question #1: q
Enter Your answer for Question #2: d
Enter Your answer for Question #3: q
Enter Your answer for Question #4: q
Enter Your answer for Question #5: q
Enter Your answer for Question #6: q
Enter Your answer for Question #7: q
Enter Your answer for Question #8: q
Enter Your answer for Question #9: q
Enter Your answer for Question #10: q

**YOU FAILED**
Number correct:  1.00
Number incorrect: 9.00



You got the following questions wrong:

Question     Correct     Your Answer
--------     -------     -----------
[(0, 'Q'), (2, 'Q'), (3, 'Q'), (4, 'Q'), (5, 'Q'), (6, 'Q'), (7, 'Q'), (8, 'Q'), (9, 'Q')]
Q
```

I don't understand why you're printing the "number right" and "number wrong" as floats.  Those will always be integers.